# Second law of thermodynamics as a theorem about state space evolution

Tags: reference-request, physics, mathematical-physics

I once saw a mathematical explanation of the second law of thermodynamics. The statement was something like this: there is a mapping $f$ from the set of thermodynamic states $S$ to itself, and a volume measure $v$ defined on $S$;  if  $f$ is a physically possible mapping that actually describes the evolution of the space in time, then for any set $A\subset S$,  $$v(A)\lt v(f(A)).$$

I am remembering this wrong, but I hope it will be recognizable, because I'd like to read more about it, and I can't remember what it is called.

Comment: Check this pdf http://www.google.com.tr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=second%20law%20mathematical%20proof%20thermodynamics&source=web&cd=16&cad=rja&ved=0CEsQFjAFOAo&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.141.2743%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=5BzCUYmNCufA4APAtYGQAw&usg=AFQjCNHxGQ83CT4LmInxuleKC_wLbBN3Cg&bvm=bv.48175248,d.dmg

Comment: That looks a lot like what I wanted, thanks. I will try to read it and see if I can abstract it enough to write an answer to my question.

Comment: Update: Still reading this paper, which is long.

Comment: (The paper is: “[The Physics and Mathematics of the Second Law of Thermodynamics](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.141.2743)”, Lieb, Elliott H. and Jakob Yngvason, 1999)

Comment: (This 101-page paper did not mention Liouville's theorem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(Hamiltonian)) of Hamiltonian mechanics.  According to the Wikipedia article, it states that:

> the phase-space distribution function is constant along the trajectories of the system—that is that the density of system points in the vicinity of a given system point traveling through phase-space is constant with time.

Note that this asserts that $v(A) = v(f(A))$, whereas in the question I asked about $v(A) < v(f(A))$.   This has something to do with increasing entropy: the *actual* phase space stays the same size, but our knowledge about where it is can only decrease, and so the *possible* region that the system currently inhabits, constrained only by our knowledge, continually increases.  This explanation is confused, but no better one has been offered in six years.  I will update if I am able to learn more.

In any case, Liouville's theorem of Hamiltonian mechanics is certainly the thing to look at.